# JAVA - Filtering through a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, jtable, filtering, jcombobox

I have a class that reads from a text file, splits the string by a delimiter and adds them to an object depending on the first line.

Now everything adds to a linkedlist which later get all represented in a JTable.

In the GUI I have a JComboBox with various Categories. What I want is to filter the JTable according to the selected item.

This is a screenshot to help you understand more:

[image]

Code:

- Processing: http://pastebin.com/4L427yDY
- GUI_g: http://pastebin.com/rfaR3ehC
- ProgramTableModel:   http://pastebin.com/eLvcfPVM

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter` for sorting *and* filtering: See [TableRowSorter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html). You'll probably have to implement your own (simple) `javax.swing.RowFilter`, see [RowFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html).

An example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=163

Comment: I tried http://pastebin.com/udvgJW7k but it returns and empty table for whichever option I choose from the JCombBox

Comment: hmm I think its that I have to ignore the case since "Music" only shows up

Comment: No problem. Btw, you only have to setup the TableRowSorter once when you create your table.

Comment: Just a quick question, how do I remove the filter? i.e. return all the list?

Comment: Simply set a null row filter: TableRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);